# Splitting the tab from barcode data using python and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, barcode, barcode-scanner, raspberry-pi4

Hi I am trying to display the barcode scanner's output in 20X4 LCD display connected with raspberry Pi . I can able to scan the barcode and display it's data in LCD screen but they are suffixed with a tab. When I scan the barcode I am getting output like this in notepad `1234567890128   1234567890128   1234567890128   705632441947    705632441947`    .You can see the tabs after each scan. How to remove those tabs using a python program or is there any alternate ways for solving it . LCD program has been written in python so a piece of python program as an example would be better. I added a single line of code for getting user input . The input will be a barcode data. Along with that data I am getting **and,if,not,or** like this `1234567890128and` `1234567890128if`  as an output . Please help me in solving this. And also I need to auto execute the scanned barcode data without pressing enter key of my keyboard. Usually after getting user input we need to press enter for executing that data. Here i need to automate this process without pressing enter I want the data to be displayed in LCD screen. Please give me some solutions.

I am attaching the program and it's output below

```
import lcddriver
from time import*
barvalue = input("Scan the barcode: ") #Getting the user input
lcd = lcddriver.lcd()
lcd.lcd_display_string("Barcode: ",1) #Displaying the 'Barcode:' in row 1 of LCD
lcd.lcd_display_string(barvalue,2,1) #Displaying the User input in row 2 of LCD
lcd.lcd_display_string("",4,1)
lcd.lcd_display_string("",3,1)
```

Output:

`1234567890128and`

[Screen shot of output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi5VN.png)

**Hardware :** Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS

**IDE:** Thonny Python with python 3

Comment: The CR at end of scan can usually be setup in the barcode reader with a special barcode : check barcode reader documentation.

Comment: @Ptit Xav. Yes you are right . Finally I got the required result by scanning a CR barcode from Scanner's documentation . Thank you Very much